# May I have some examples of “future perfect continuous” from fiction or literature, with references?

Tags: tenses, word-usage, future, future-perfect, continuous-aspect

Question says it all and again it should be from literature or fiction.

I was told that the future perfect continuous does not exist. So I am looking for examples from “real published and acclaimed books”.

Comment: [Future perfect continuous exists](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureperfectcontinuous.html)

Comment: Gene Wolfe, *The Citadel of the Autarch* (1982) “It is about half as wide as the one you **will have been following.”**

Comment: So someone will have been telling you lies in order for you to arrive here

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I’m pretty sure we’ll find that he will have been being lied to.

Comment: He is not going to have been lied to after having been here for a while

Comment: I think your question is too broad, since you're asking for a list, but could be improved by asking something like "does this tense occur at all in literature?" That way it has a yes or no answer which better fits the site.

Comment: Future Superperfect Tense: _You'll have to have had it in your possession for at least 24 hours, or the spell won't work._

Answer (score 2):

In "[At the Back of the Black Man's Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_the_Back_of_the_Black_Man%27s_Mind)" from 1906, comes the sentence:

"*Here, after he himself has given out or started his last song, which is to be taken up by the large assembly of people who will have been waiting to hear his last word or his last groan, his head is taken off and his blood offered to the gods.*"

[Link to a Google Books Preview](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wDjDzFeRbl8C&pg=PA263&dq=%22will%20have%20been%20waiting%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mYHVUdjSFom57Abkh4HQBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22will%20have%20been%20waiting%22&f=false)